# Quick way to spot non- #N/A without array formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this sheet:

[image]

The yellow cell has this formula:

`{=IF(SUM(IFERROR(B10:M15,0),0)>0,1,0)}`

Can this be done without an array formula?

Comment: @pnuts ....classic example of me over-complicating things!! I initially saw that `SUM(b10:m15)` returned `#N/A` and assumed that something complicated was required. Trivial I know but you should put that as the answer.

Comment: @pnuts ....I don't generally delete questions, however silly they seem [(check this one)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369682/applying-vbcrlf-to-the-content-of-a-textbox). I ended up using `IFERROR` to replace all the `NA`s with `""`s: then rather than your answer I could use `SUM`

Comment: @pnuts not exactly `SUM` but `=IF(ABS(SUM(F49:BS54))>0,1,0)`...I suppose there is a very small chance of one cell showing say `10` and another showing `-10` in which case `SUM` will be a bad choice - so I can use `=IF(COUNT(Q41:BS46)>0,1,0)` instead.

Comment: @pnuts agreed - in the context I have it is unlikely p.s.cool use of `1` in `=1*(COUNT(F46:BS54)<>0)`

Comment: Instead of `*1`, I prefer `--`. Same effect (casting booleans to 0 or 1), but marginally faster to type (though marginally slower in calculation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first though of this formula (which works):

```
=COUNTA(B10:M15)-COUNTIF(B10:M15,NA())
```

but then, pnuts formula is even better and also work: `=COUNT(B10:M15)`, so best use this!

Comment: I never saw that use of a semi-colon ... `COUNTIF(B10:M15;NA())`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Forgot to change from regional (German) to international format...

Comment: @pnuts: Fair point - though esp. with beginners (more on SU than on SO) you get those "but the formula doesn't work for me"), which I try to prevent... Certainly not an issue for whytec, but generally I guess it's good practise to post in the english locale...

Comment: @PeterAlbert "SU" Stack...?

Comment: @whytheq: SU=SuperUser - the SO for non programmers/powerusers